# Will a Cross Apply bail, but not error in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2005

We're inserting a couple millions records into a details table, the data for which is stored in the master table in CSV type format. To do the insert we're using a cross apply function, which seems to work if I do the inserts one by one, but if I do the entire insert, only about 2/3 of the records go in, and the query just stops, with success after about 3 and half hours.

Here's the insert query

```
   INSERT INTO DetailsTable(MasterTableID, DetailColumn1, DetailColumn2) 
   SELECT MasterTableID, DetailColumn1, DetailColumn2 FROM MasterTable
   CROSS APPLY [fn_CreateDetailData](MasterTableID, '§')
```

If I do the following for one of the records that doesn't get inserted, everthing will work fine and there record is inserted just fine

```
   INSERT INTO DetailsTable(MasterTableID, DetailColumn1, DetailColumn2) 
   SELECT MasterTableID, DetailColumn1, DetailColumn2 FROM MasterTable
   CROSS APPLY [fn_CreateDetailData](MasterTableID, '§') 
   WHERE MasterTableID = 12345
```

From everything I've ever known about SQL Server, a single insert statement exists in one transaction, so its either all or nothing, but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: The only reason for this to happen is that your function filters the other rows out.  
Show us your function.

Comment: How can my function filter the rows out when I don't specify the primary key id, but not filter it out when I do?

Unfortunately, this seems like a problem that is too specific for StackOverflow to be able to handle.

Comment: Here's the thing, if I just run the function more times, I get more and more new unique rows being inserted, that's what seems so strange.

Answer (score 2):

Is this **exactly** your code, for the SELECT? Have you ommitted any detail like, say, use of NOLOCK hints? NOLOCK is notorious for causing misterious gaps in data, see [Previously committed rows might be missed if NOLOCK hint is used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlcat/previously-committed-rows-might-be-missed-if-nolock-hint-is-used)

Comment: Well, its not EXACTLY my code, as we don't really have a table called MasterTable. But aside from renaming the columns and the table, it is exactly what I run.